# Invalid path using karateFeature in performance test

Tags: karate

I am getting path not found
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found: gratling/simulation/orderServices/getOrderRequest.feature

Below is what is written in scala file.

```
package gratling.simulation.orderServices

class OrderSimulation extends Simulation {

  val getOrderRequest = scenario("getOrderRequestScenario").forever 
  {
     exec(
        feed(csv("data/getOrderRequest.csv").batch.circular)
        .exec(karateFeature(PathFinder.getPath("getOrderRequest.feature")))
        .pause(pace seconds)
     )
  }
}
```

getOrderRequest.feature is place in the directory

```
src
└── test
    └── resources
        └── gratling
            └── simulation
                └── orderServices
                   └──getOrderRequest.feature
```

By using Paths, I will have no issues running the script as shown below

val orderFilePath= Paths.get("C:/XXX/src/test/scala/gratling/simulation/orderServices/getOrderRequest.feature").toAbsolutePath.toString

```
   val getOrderRequest= scenario("getOrderRequestScenario").forever {
        exec(
            feed(csv("data/getOrderRequest.csv").batch.circular)
            .exec(karateFeature(orderFilePath))
            .pause(pace seconds))}
```

But I am trying to use the below dynamically instead of hardcoding the path

```
karateFeature(PathFinder.getPath("getOrderRequest.feature"))
```

In pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
     <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${gatling.trial.run.plugin.version}</version>
     <configuration>
        <simulationsFolder>src/test/scala</simulationsFolder>
         <runMultipleSimulations>true</runMultipleSimulations>
         <includes>
                 <include>gratling.simulation.orderServices.OrderSimulation</include>
          </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `karateFeature()` API is designed to use the [same system that Karate uses](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#reading-files).

So try this:

```
karateFeature("classpath:gratling/simulation/orderServices/getOrderRequest.feature"))
```

Else it is hard to troubleshoot, try your best to align with the [documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#maven) / [sample projects](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/gatling).

Comment: Yes. I have re organized into src/test/scala and add this. It works perfectly! 
```
karateFeature("classpath:orderServices/getOrderRequest.feature")
```